# What's the correct syntax to call the equality comparer for String.Contains method?

Tags: vb.net

I searched for this before posting, but all examples I saw were for C#, and apparently, they don't work the same way in VB.NET.

Visual Studio is throwing an error when I pass the string comparison overload below to the `Contains` method.

What's the proper syntax for this?

```
     'Job sequence is part of the full path?
     If strJobNCFile.Contains(strJobSequence, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        intPassCounter += 1
        WriteDataToLog("Job sequence check ('" & strJobSequence & "') - PASS !", txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
     Else
        arrIntJobsThatWillBeKilled.Add(Convert.ToInt32(strJobID))
        WriteDataToLog("The job sequence '" & strJobSequence & "' is NOT part of the path '" & strJobNCFile & "' !!!" & vbNewLine, txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
     End If
```

---

I tried this, and I get no errors in the IDE, but it throws an exception at runtime.

```
       'Job sequence is part of the full path?
       If strJobNCFile.Contains(strJobSequence, comparer:=StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
          intPassCounter += 1
          WriteDataToLog("Job sequence check ('" & strJobSequence & "') - PASS !", txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
       Else
          arrIntJobsThatWillBeKilled.Add(Convert.ToInt32(strJobID))
          WriteDataToLog("The job sequence '" & strJobSequence & "' is NOT part of the path '" & strJobNCFile & "' !!!" & vbNewLine, txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
       End If
```

---

However, this seems to work with the `EndsWith` method:

```
     If strJobNCFile.EndsWith(strLastFolderPlusNCFile, comparisonType:=StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) Then
        intPassCounter += 1
        WriteDataToLog("NC-File path check '...\" & strLastFolderPlusNCFile & "') - PASS !" & vbNewLine, txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
     Else
        arrIntJobsThatWillBeKilled.Add(Convert.ToInt32(strJobID))
        WriteDataToLog("The path '" & strJobNCFile & "' does NOT contain the file and sub-folder '...\" & strLastFolderPlusNCFile & "' as part of it !!!" & vbNewLine, txtMiscellaneousLogPath.Text)
     End If
```

[image]

Comment: jmcilhinney has a solution for this: [Thread: Error message with String.Contains Method](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887295-Error-message-with-String-Contains-Method).

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` as the first line of your code file. You will see it's calling `IEnumerable(Of Char).Contains()` and there will be a compile-time error.

Answer (score -2):

This works perfect for me.

```
If strJobNCFile.Contains(strJobSequence) Then

...

...

End If
```

Comment: And what happens if you use the overload that takes two parameters with a version of .NET which does not implement that, as the OP appears to be trying to do?